# Smart way of writing sql Join

Tags: mysql

I was exploring someone's code and I have found this query.This query is fetching data using join. But there is no use of inner join, outer join, left or right. The programmer simply writes this query.

I found this is the SMART way of writing query, if this query is right ?

```
SELECT 
    a.*,b.*,c.*,d.*,e.* 
FROM  
    property_photos a,property_promotions b,properties c, communities d,cities e 
WHERE 
    a.property_id = b.property_id AND 
    a.property_id = c.id AND 
    (b.promotion_id =2 OR b.promotion_id =1) AND 
    a.mainphoto="Y" AND 
    d.id=c.community_id AND 
    e.id = c.city_id AND 
    a.featured_status = 1
```

Is this query correct?

It this query is right, the i think, this is more better way to write queries since it will save a lot of disk space instead of use Left join/right Join like words which makes query long

SMARTY WAY

Comment: of course, If he has written this means he must have tested!!!!and it works...No fault appears in syntax or logic...

Comment: I believe one question mark will do to point out it is a question.

Comment: Yes, it working, but as i think the right way is select a.*, b.data from table a inner join b on b.id =a.id. This is example of inner join. But above query is not like this. Which type of join is using above query ????????????

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it is alright. It is the same as an INNER JOIN.

Note:

> Which Syntax to Use? Per the ANSI SQL specification, use of the INNER
>   JOIN syntax is preferable. Furthermore, although using the WHERE
>   clause to define joins is indeed simpler, using explicit join syntax
>   ensures that you will never forget the join condition, and it can
>   affect performance, too (in some cases).

Source: [Sam's - MySQL Crash Course, page 139](http://www.techrepublic.com/i/tr/downloads/home/0672327120_chapter_15.pdf)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, this is known as **implicit** `JOIN` syntax. It has fallen out of favour once ANSI-92 defined an **explicit** `JOIN` syntax, which is an order of magnitude easier to read as your queries get more complex.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29):

SQL specifies two different syntactical ways to express joins: "explicit join notation" and "implicit join notation".

The "explicit join notation" uses the JOIN keyword to specify the table to join, and the ON keyword to specify the predicates for the join, as in the following example:

```
SELECT *
FROM employee
INNER JOIN department ON employee.DepartmentID = department.DepartmentID;
```

The "implicit join notation" simply lists the tables for joining, in the FROM clause of the SELECT statement, using commas to separate them. Thus it specifies a cross join, and the WHERE clause may apply additional filter-predicates (which function comparably to the join-predicates in the explicit notation).

The following example is equivalent to the previous one, but this time using implicit join notation:

```
SELECT *
FROM employee, department
WHERE employee.DepartmentID = department.DepartmentID;
```

Comment: what about performance ????????????

Comment: In MySQL >= 5.5, they're not *entirely* equivalent (although in your example it happens that they are): the parser now gives higher precedence to explicit join than it does to implicit join, which can cause a few surprises if one is not expecting it.  Search [`JOIN` Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/join.html) for "precedence".

Comment: if they're not entirely equivalent, then what will be the type of join using in above query ?. still say implicit ????????

Comment: @shail Please reduce the number of question marks you type, my eyes are bleeding.